# easiest way to setup XEmacs on Gentoo for Python

Tags: python, emacs, xemacs

I want to use (X)Emacs on my Gentoo system and wonder about the "correct" (or easiest) way to setup it to be used for Python development (i.e. intelligent auto-completion via tab and all those usual stuff).

I want to avoid installing anything by hand - I want to use my Portage/emerge as far as possible.

I have installed xemacs, python-mode and python-modes so far. Seems that I had to manually enable syntax highlighting and the syntax highlighting support seems kind of limited. And auto completion via tab doesn't work at all (I guess it's also not enabled or python-mode(s) doesn't have that?).

Thanks for your help!

Comment: you will need to tell emacs to start python-mode when you open a .py file, you do this in your .emacs file.

Answer (score 0):

I used this tutorial myself at [EnigmaCurry](http://www.enigmacurry.com/2009/01/21/autocompleteel-python-code-completion-in-emacs/).

You can use easy_install to install rope and ropemacs. And then I believe you only need to copy the autocomplete.el script on that site.

good luck.